# Reading annotation property in aspect

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

How to read annotation property value in aspect?

I want my ***Around*** advice to be executed for all joint points annotated with ***@Transactional(readonly=false)***.

```
@Around("execution(* com.mycompany.services.*.*(..)) "
+ "&& @annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
public Object myMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it without manual processing of signature, this way (`argNames` is used to keep argument names when compiled without debug information):

```
@Around(
    value = "execution(* com.mycompany.services.*.*(..)) && @annotation(tx)",
    argNames = "tx") 
public Object myMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Transactional tx) 
    throws Throwable {
    ...
}
```

See [7.2.4.6 Advice parameters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this this way:

Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Profiled {
    public boolean showArguments();
}
```

Interceptor:

```
@Aspect
public class ProfilingAspect {

    public static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ProfilingAspect");

    @Around("@annotation(profiled)")
    public Object profiled(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
            final Profiled profiled) throws Throwable {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        try {
            sw.start();
            return pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            sw.stop();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Method ");
            sb.append(pjp.getSignature().getName());
            if (profiled.showArguments()) {
                sb.append(" with arguments ");
                sb.append(Arrays.toString(pjp.getArgs()));
            }
            sb.append(" took ");
            sb.append(sw.getTime());
            sb.append(" millis");
            log.info(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you will have to do it in the code. For example

```
Signature s = pjp.getSugnature();
Method m = s.getDeclaringType().getDeclaredMethod(s.getName(), pjp.getArgs());
Transactional transactional = m.getAnnotation(Transactional.class);
if (transactional != null && !transactional.readOnly()) {
   // code
}
```

But are you really sure you want to mess with transaction handling?

Comment: I hopped that there is a way to do this using Around annotations. Thanks for reply anyway.

Comment: Yep. I want to retry operation in case of OptimisticLockException