# Aspect pointcut to match Annotation property

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to use Spring AOP with AspectJ support to weave methods with a certain annotation. I know it's easy to do so by using a pointcut @annotation(classname)

But I need to create weavers based on properties of the annotation. The annotation in question is Spring's @RequestMapping, and I need to check the method property of it.

I know I could access it inside the body of the advice, but what I really would like is to create one advice per matched annotation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There [doesn't seem to be a way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2499697/301832), but you can check the parameters of the annotation immediately on entry and immediately pass it on if they're not satisfied.

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(reqMap)")
public Object myMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, RequestMapping reqMap)
        throws Throwable {
    if (notRightPropertyValue(reqMap))
        return pjp.proceed();
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

If this is too inelegant, consider inventing an extra annotation to mark just the methods that you're really interested in.